# lable.text - Fatal Error

Tags: ios, swift, fatal-error

I have 2 classes.
In first class I have a label and a button and in second class I have JsonPars function

I need to write a data from second class to the label in first class.

Here is my code:

```
    import UIKit
    import CoreLocation

    //main class

    class ViewController: UIViewController{


    @IBOutlet weak var labl: UILabel!

    @IBAction func btn(sender: AnyObject) {
        Json().Pars()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

and second class:

```
import Foundation

//Json-class
class Json {
    func Pars() {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://my.url.com")
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil){
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?

        let parseObj: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &err)

        if let json = parseObj as? NSDictionary{
            if let response = json["response"] as? NSDictionary{
               if let obj = response["Object"] as? NSDictionary{
                    if let data = obj["data"] as? NSString {
                       println(data)//work's and i have a data
                       ViewController().labl.text = data //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value


                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        })

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Sorry fo my English

Comment: Please shorten your example code to just include what is necessary to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're creating a new instance of `ViewController` when you call `ViewController()`. Since you haven't presented the view controller it's outlets haven't been set and are `nil`. Therefore when you try to access `labl` (an implicitly unwrapped optional), it's equal to `nil` and your app crashes.

To fix this, perhaps `pars()` (it's convention to use lower case for methods) could return the data, which you would then have access to in your `ViewController` class.

Comment: so i must to get label - some value in ViewController class, and then to change my data in Json class?

Answer (score -2):

Sorry I'm in class on my Lenovo so I can't test this, but try:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
```

I normally do that just in case I need it at some point. Also if that fails maybe try sending data to the viewcontroller then applying it to label.text.

EDIT: You also have this:

```
})
```

above task.resume, please review that and see if that doesn't fix it.